# Using Println function Inside a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, console

I have been assigned to make my console program output the following:

Grid
(1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6) (1, 7)
(2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6) (2, 7)
(3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6) (3, 7)
(4, 1) (4, 2) (4, 3) (4, 4) (4, 5) (4, 6) (4, 7)
(5, 1) (5, 2) (5, 3) (5, 4) (5, 5) (5, 6) (5, 7)
(6, 1) (6, 2) (6, 3) (6, 4) (6, 5) (6, 6) (6, 7)
(7, 1) (7, 2) (7, 3) (7, 4) (7, 5) (7, 6) (7, 7)

I think I need to use a for loop then put print inside but I don't really know how I would arrange the logic... Can someone point me into the right direction?

UPDATE
Here is the solution:

```
    for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y <= 7; y++) {
            System.out.print("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            if (y == 7) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if this is homework please tag as such.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: where are you planning to keep these values? In a 2D array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would need two loops.  Something like

```
for(i = 1; i < 8; i++){
   for(j = 1; j < 8; j++){
      // print code here
   }
}
```

since this is homework, you should try to figure out the rest.

Conceptually, the way this works is you have the outer loop.  As it runs, `i` is 1, then 2, then 3, etc.

You also have the inner loop.  As it runs `j` is 1, then 2, then 3, etc....

Since the inner loop is inside the outer loop, when `i` is 1, the inner loop goes thru **ALL** of its values.  Now look at what you are supposed to print...

Comment: I tried the following:  
for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x++) {  
            for (int y = 1; y <= 7; y++) {  
                System.out.print(x+", "+y);  
            }  
        }  
  
  
It didn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: The following was outputted:

1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 72, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 73, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 74, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 75, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 76, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 77, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 7BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: you need to add more to your print statement.  It needs () and , characters too...eg something like `"(" + x ...`

Comment: @VaughnSimon so you can see what it does and what it should do.  Once you work out what the difference is you will be able to determine what you need to add.

Comment: I now have Grid
(1, 1)(1, 2)(1, 3)(1, 4)(1, 5)(1, 6)(1, 7)(2, 1)(2, 2)(2, 3)(2, 4)(2, 5)(2, 6)(2, 7)(3, 1)(3, 2)(3, 3)(3, 4)(3, 5)(3, 6)(3, 7)(4, 1)(4, 2)(4, 3)(4, 4)(4, 5)(4, 6)(4, 7)(5, 1)(5, 2)(5, 3)(5, 4)(5, 5)(5, 6)(5, 7)(6, 1)(6, 2)(6, 3)(6, 4)(6, 5)(6, 6)(6, 7)(7, 1)(7, 2)(7, 3)(7, 4)(7, 5)(7, 6)(7, 7)

Comment: How do I make it so there is a new line after y=7?

Comment: so every time the inner loop ends, you want to print a `\n` character.  so just put another print statement at the appropriate place.

Comment: Im not following... I tried this and it made every line has a break:
for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= 7; y++) {
                System.out.print("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }

Comment: System.out.println("\nGrid");

        for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= 7; y++) {
                System.out.print("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                if (y == 7) {
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }

Comment: you should upvote and/or checkmark when there are answers that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You would need two loops; one to iterate over the rows and the other to iterate over the columns in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to use nested loops. Implement the following pseudocode in Java:

```
for 1 to 7 
  for 1 to 7
    print ( first number, second number )
  print new line
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), please tag appropriately.

But to answer your question without actualy writing the code, here's the hint: use nested `for` loop.